# Error connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting this error and unable to fix this.

events.js:72

```
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
```

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)

```
var http = require('http');


var options = {
host: 'localhost',
port: '8081',
path: '/index.htm'  
};


 var callback = function(response){

 var body = '';
 response.on('data', function(data) {
   body += data;
});

response.on('end', function() {

  console.log(body);
 });

 }

var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.end();
```

Comment: what happens if you access http://localhost:8081/index.htm in your browser? aren't you missing the "l" char of the "html"?

Comment: It is unable to access  localhost:8081/index.html.  I put 'l' char in "html" , error still same.

Comment: There's no server running on localhost port 8081.

Comment: I agree with @robertklep. What was supposed to be returned from this address?

Comment: I just want to return "hello world" on index.html.  i am just start with Node.